# Ajax request in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backslash

I want to make an ajax request in javascript/jquery to call web service, but I don't understand something :

With this 2 pictures, it's more simple to explain you my issue :

PICTURE 1 : with username = '\j' I get 'j' after ajax request

[image]

PICTURE 2 : with username = '\\j' I get '\\j' after ajax request

[image]

How can I get '\j' after ajax request ??

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that it's just an issue in the console. Have you checked what the server actually receives?

Comment: `"\\j"` is correct; you'll end up with `"\j"`, as the first backslash escapes the second.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with "How can I get '\j' after ajax request